# Populate Ember View.Select object on each transition to page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, transition, controllers

New Ember user here,

I am having an issue trying to get a dropdown view to be populated with initial values from a model on transition to any one of multiple edit routes. I am currently using fixture data...

My **router** is setup as such:

```
StoryTime.Router.map(function () {

    this.resource('projects', function(){

        this.resource('project', { path: '/:project_id' }, function(){

            this.resource('stories', function(){

                this.resource('story', { path: '/:story_id' }, function(){

                    this.route('edit');
                });
            });

            this.route('edit');
            this.route('report');
            this.route('export');

        });

        this.route('new');
    });
});
```

with a **route** for editing a story as:

```
StoryTime.StoryEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model',  this.controllerFor('story').get('model'));
    }
});
```

and my **controller** setup as:

```
StoryTime.StoryEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    needs:['story', 'project'],

    actors:  Ember.computed.alias('controllers.project.actors'),

    selectedActor: null,

    updateActor: function(){

        var actor = this.get('selectedActor'),
            model = this.get('model');

        model.set('actor', actor);

    }.observes('selectedActor'),

    actions: {
        //actions...
    }
});
```

and my **template** has this piece in question in it:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 text-left no-padding">Actor:</label>
        <div class="controls col-sm-10">
            {{model.actor.name}}: {{model.actor.id}}
            {{view Ember.Select
                name             = "actorSelect"
                content          = actors
                optionLabelPath  = "content.name"
                optionValuePath  = "content.id"
                selectionBinding = "selectedActor"
                class            = "form-control"
            }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

My preferable setup would have:

- The model being given to the controller (set by the story edit route to be the model given to the stories route) populate the dropdown box's initial value, but then binds the subsequent selection to the controllers attribute for processing, and
- The controller changes the "selectedActor" attribute to null again on transition to another edit route.

Right now, this is not happening. Here's what **is** happening:

- When I navigate to .../stories/1/edit for example, the dropdown is not populated to the model's actor value, but rather the first thing in the list
- If I change the value it changes the controller's model's actor, as expected.
- However, on subsequent transitions to ../stories/2/edit the dropdown is still populated with the old selected value due to "selectedActor" being set to it.

Can anyone illuminate as to what I am missing here? I feel like there has to be way to both work with the Ember Select view and a way to reset attributes of a particular route or controller on transition. Am I incorrect on this thinking?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: change you Ember.Select, instead of selectionBinding = 'selectedActor' user 'actor'. With that, you're binding the value directly to the one the current model has, as soon as you enter a new route, the Select should show the one that belongs to the current model(Story), and as soon as you change the Select, the Story's actor will be updated. You do not need the selectedActor property, nor the observer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, fanta is right. You just need to remove a whole bunch of code from your controller and modify your template slightly. Replace your controller and template like so:

```
StoryTime.StoryEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:['story', 'project'],
    actors:  Ember.computed.alias('controllers.project.actors'),
    actions: {
        //actions...
    }
});


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 text-left no-padding">Actor:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-10">
        {{actor.name}}: {{actor.id}}
        {{view Ember.Select
            name             = "actorSelect"
            content          = actors
            optionLabelPath  = "content.name"
            optionValuePath  = "content.id"
            selectionBinding = actor
            class            = "form-control"
        }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Note you don't need model references in your template. Ember will automatically pass the references back to the underlying model. The primarily job of the controller is to decorate and provide the model (and handle actions & events) to the template / views.

Comment: Thanks folks, this seemed to work and I understand the approach. My concern with this is now it doesn't seem to choose the appropriate actor value on transition. That is to say it always reverts to the first thing in the dropdown. Any way around this?

Comment: Sorry I think you should have selection = actor, or selectionBinding = "actor". I seem to have written that incorrectly. Could you please build a jsbin with your example in it if that doesn't solve your issue?